# Assert a string as being apart of a subset of strings in typescript

Tags: typescript, cucumber, cucumberjs

In one of my scenarios in cucumber, I have a regex which matches either button or link and puts that as a parameter in the callback function

```
Given(
  /^I click the (button|link) with text "([^"]+)" exactly$/,
  async function (this: ICustomWorld, role: string, text: string) {
    const page = this.page!;
    await page.getByRole(role, { name: text, exact: true }).click();
  },
);
```

However it gives me an error saying that `Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type "alert" | "alertdialog"| "application" ...`.

I wonder if there is a way to maybe say `role = 'button' | 'link'` to tell the interpreter that `role` will only have the value `button` or `link`?

Comment: `role: "button" | "link"`, but you may find that's not then a valid argument to Given. You might have to type assert this, or write a custom type predicate to give the compiler additional information.